# Show $\forall q\in \mathbb{Q},\:\:g\left(q\right)\:\ge \:f\left(q\right).\:$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\:\:\:\:g\left(x\right)\:\ge \:f\left(x\right)?$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f,\:g$ be continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$.
if $\forall q\in \mathbb{Q},\:\:\:\:g\left(q\right)\:\ge \:f\left(q\right)$ ,how to prove that $\:$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\:\:\:\:g\left(x\right)\:\ge \:f\left(x\right)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h = g - f$. Then you have to show that if $h(q) \ge 0$ for all rationals $q$, then $h(x) \ge 0$ for all real $x$.

Suppose not; suppose that $h(x_0) = a < 0$. Pick $\epsilon = -a/2 > 0$. For every positive $\delta$, there's a rational number $q$ in the interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, and for that $q$, we have $h(q) \ge 0$, so $|h(q) - h(x_0)| > \epsilon$. Thus $h$ is not continuous at $x_0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: In the second sentence it should be $h(x) \geq 0$ instead of $h(x) > 0$. However, I can't edit the answer because edits need to be 6 characters long :)